# How to plot a function with one variable for several parameter values?

Tags: r

Good afternoon !

I have the following function of the variable n :

```
P(n) = 1-(1-p)^n
```

- p is a parameter in the interval [0 , 1]

**I'm wanting to plot this one dimentional function with several values of p , within the same plot :**

```
p=seq(0 , 1 , 0.1 )
```

So i tried for p=0.1 and p=0.9 :

```
p=0.1

n <- seq(0, 100, 8) ;  y <- 1-(1-p)^n 

plot(n , y ,pch= 21,type = "o", col = "red", xlab = "n-values", ylab = "P(n) values ", main = "P(n)= 1-(1-p)^n ")

p=0.9

lines(n , 1-(1-p)^n , type="o", pch=16 , col="blue") 

legend(60 , 0.4, c("p=0.1","p=0.9"), cex=0.7, col=c("red", "blue"),pch=c(21, 16))
```

This gives :

[image]

**The problem :**

- I'm searching an elegant way to plot this function for all values of
  p=seq(0,1,0.1) within the same plot . I'm wanting to delete the
  extrapolation effect ( I'm wanting to delete the `pch` symbols at
  all , the graph sould contains the curves with different colors and without the effect of extrapoling segments ).
- I wish my question is clear.

  Thank you for help in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `outer` and `matplot`, more x values and a suitable color scheme:

```
n <- seq(0, 100, length.out=200)
p <- seq(0.1, 1, 0.1)
f <- function(n, p) 1-(1-p)^n
M <- outer(n, p, "f")
col <- hcl.colors(length(p), "Spectral")
matplot(n, M, type = "l", col = col, lty = 1)
legend("bottomright", legend = p, col = col, lty = 1)
```

Comment: Error in hcl.colors(length(p), "Spectral") : 
  could not find function "hcl.colors"

Comment: Which R version do you use? If it is an older one, try for example `col <- topo.colors(length(p))`

Comment: "R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)"

Comment: [1] "#4C00FFFF" "#0019FFFF" "#0080FFFF" "#00E5FFFF" "#00FF4DFF" "#4DFF00FF" "#E6FF00FF" "#FFFF00FF"
 [9] "#FFDE59FF" "#FFE0B3FF"

Comment: These are the codes of topo colors. What do you want to tell with this?

Comment: Nothing , i updated now my r version . Thank you for your precious help !

Answer (score 2):

Another simply way is replacing

```r
lines(n , 1-(1-p)^n , type="o", pch=16 , col="blue")
```

with

```r
p = seq(0,1,0.1)
invisible(lapply(p, function(i) {lines(n, 1-(1-i)^n, type="o", col=i*10)}))
```